# Search contact by phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my app, user writes a phone number, and I want to find the contact name with that phone number?

I usually search the contacts like this:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
```

But I do this to access all contacts... In this app I only want to get the contact name of the given phone number... How can I restrict the query?

Or do I have to go trough all contacts and see if any has the given phone number? But I believe that this can be very slow this way...

Comment: Read the documentation about what all those nulls can be replaced with :)

Comment: Also, you want to use `CONTENT_FILTER_URI`.

Comment: For the facility of others, I have written a post which contains the whole code to query name, photo, contact ID, etc. with decent explanation. The code contains snippets as found on different answers, but more organized and tested. Hope it helps. Link: http://hellafun.weebly.com/home/get-information-of-a-contact-from-number

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should have a look at the recommended [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) provider

A table that represents the result of looking up a phone number, for example for caller ID. To perform a lookup you must append the number you want to find to CONTENT_FILTER_URI. This query is highly optimized.

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,...
```

Comment: Thanks. Im trying to call getContentResolver() in my broadcast receiver, but it looks like that function doesnt exist...

Comment: Try to prefix the context param you have, so be it context.getContentResolver()

Comment: What specifically goes into the rest of that query? This answer isn't much more helpful than the already existing documentation.

Comment: There you enumerate other columns from `PhoneLookup` for return.

Comment: any idea how to search by phone number _or_ name? Edit: that would be CDK.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, as it seems

Comment: How come it returns a cursor with multiple results in it? Are they multiple contacts?

Answer (score 90):

If you want the complete code:

```
public String getContactDisplayNameByNumber(String number) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    String name = "?";

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);

    try {
        if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
            contactLookup.moveToNext();
            name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            //String contactId = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
        }
    } finally {
        if (contactLookup != null) {
            contactLookup.close();
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't initialize the `name` variable as `null` is an appropriate return value when there are no records.

Comment: What about the special cases, where the user entered a partial number , yet the numbers stored in a format that doesn't match it? For example, in Israel the country prefix is "+972" , and for some cell phone numbers, you add "050", but if it's the full number, it becomes "97250" ( without the first "0") . So, if the user types "050" (to search all phone numbers that has it or at least start with it) , it won't get any result...

Comment: In my case, I implemented a function to filter a raw number and make all possible combinations, and then I search one by one. Unfortunately I think Android does not have a way to simplify this. Am I wrong?

Comment: How to search for multiple phone numbers?