# How to get Contact Name through Phone Number

Tags: java, android

I need to directly get the contact name (if registered in contact list) through the contact number.

I can do the opposite (get number through name) with this code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    "DISPLAY_NAME = '"someone"'", null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                String contactId =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {

                    String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                    int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                    Log.v("TAG3",number);
                    ...
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I can't honestly do the opposite. Can you please guys help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search contact by phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712112/search-contact-by-phone-number)

Comment: this is duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712112/search-contact-by-phone-number

Comment: Thanks, and sorry. I completely missed.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323025/how-to-get-contact-name-by-sending-contact-number-in-android

Comment: For the facility of others, I have written a post which contains the whole code to query name, photo, contact ID, etc. with decent explanation. The code contains snippets as found on different answers, but more organized and tested. Hope it helps. Link: http://hellafun.weebly.com/home/get-information-of-a-contact-from-number