# how to get contact name by sending contact number in android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

if there any method to get contact name by send contact number in android.if any one have idea .

```
private String getContactName(String string) {
         String name=null;
          ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
          Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
             while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                 String id =  cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                  name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
             }
               } 
        return name;
    }
```

I am sending contact number to these method.How to get contact name.

Comment: For the facility of others, I have written a post which contains the whole code to query name, photo, contact ID, etc. with decent explanation. The code contains snippets as found on different answers, but more organized and tested. Hope it helps. Link: http://hellafun.weebly.com/home/get-information-of-a-contact-from-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by do like these.

```
public static String getContactName(final String phoneNumber,Context context) {
        Uri uri;
        String[] projection;
        Uri mBaseUri = Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL;
        projection = new String[] { android.provider.Contacts.People.NAME };
        try {
            Class<?> c = Class
                    .forName("android.provider.ContactsContract$PhoneLookup");
            mBaseUri = (Uri) c.getField("CONTENT_FILTER_URI").get(mBaseUri);
            projection = new String[] { "display_name" };
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(mBaseUri, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        String contactName = "";

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        cursor = null;
        return contactName;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use following method to get contact, from contact provider:

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(string));

Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
```

This cursor will have resultset having number same as string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Uri uri;
String[] projection;
Uri baseUri = Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL;
projection = new String[] { android.provider.Contacts.People.NAME };
try {
Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.provider.ContactsContract$PhoneLookup");
baseUri = (Uri) c.getField("CONTENT_FILTER_URI").get(baseUri);
projection = new String[] { "display_name" };
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, Uri.encode(Uri
            .encode(phoneNumber)));
Cursor cursor =mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri,
            projection, null, null, null) ;

String fromDisplayName = null;
if (cursor != null) {
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    fromDisplayName = cursor.getString(0);
}
else{
    fromDisplayName="";
}
cursor.close();
} else {
    fromDisplayName="";
}
return fromDisplayName;
```

The Uri android.provider.Contacts.People.NAME is deprecated. But android.provider.ContactsContract$PhoneLookup is available from API level 5 only. Hence it is better to use reflections to support all phones.