# How to search number from contacts in android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am developing an application in that I have to search numbers from contacts and add that contact to my edit text. I wrote some code it go to contacts but not add in edit text please tell me any mistake in my code

my code

```
  searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });

     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RESULT_OK){
         Uri contactData = data.getData();
         Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                 (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        //contactName.setText(name);
        ephoneNumber.setText(number);
        //contactEmail.setText(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote is a contact picker. Which takes you to contacts app and allows you to pick a contact which you can use in your app

Comment: It doesn't search any number. Explain what you are trying to achieve clearly

Comment: whenever i clicked search button it will go to contacts in my mobile

Comment: are u getting the content of string "number" just before u settext it to ephoneNumber??..try putting a Log there and check.

Comment: ok. So, what you want is to search a particular number in your contacts and display the name. Then answer given by @AbdEl-Rahman should solve it.

Comment: But make sure you give READ_CONTACTS permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ContentResolver` to do this. Call this method to get the `contact` name:

```
public String getContactDisplayNameByNumber(String number) {
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
String name = "?";

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,
        ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);

try {
    if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
        contactLookup.moveToNext();
        name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
        //String contactId = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
    }
} finally {
    if (contactLookup != null) {
        contactLookup.close();
    }
}

return name;
}
```

This method will return the Name of your desired number from contact list. The code reference is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712112/search-contact-by-phone-number)

Comment: No problem, when the code enter scoop of retrieving the name, that`s means that your number is exist in the `contacts`. Then do whatever action you want. I assume that you know how to do this small modification :) @Durga

Comment: i did not understand how to call from search button

Comment: Call the method and give it the number as an input and make it return True after the line (name = contactLookup....)

Comment: how to get that parameter

Comment: You can get it from the user as an input using `EditText` and get it input after clicking the `button` by `editText.getText().toString()`

Comment: my requirement is search contacts number and if i select any number i should be add in my edit text

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48556/discussion-between-durga-and-abd-el-rahman-el-tamawy)

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch name or number both

```
// fetch contact name from phone directory
    public String fetchNamePhone(String number){

        String numberName= null;

        /// number is the phone number
        Uri lookupUri =     Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(number));

        String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };                                                                                  

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null,null);

        try {
            if(c.moveToFirst()){

                 return number;
                // numberName =      c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
            }
           else{
              number = "";
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return number;
    }
```

After call this function , you will check number.length if greater then 1 then number is available otherwise number is not available